# I want to refresh the div only if the record is updated in sql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have developed a voting system so I am wondering if you guyz can help me out with the issue. I have placed a query using javascript of setinterval for loading data after every 2 seconds but I tried to do so but it is not happening it is not working for me can anyone help me out there is no errors found and when I checked it is not showing the updated data

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
setInterval(function(){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
    var url = "includes/votings.php";
    var vars = "records=records&gender=Female";
    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            var returndata = req.responseText;
            var currenttime = myDate.getTime();
            if(currenttime > returndata) {
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
                setInterval(function(){$("#ratewomen").load("includes/votings.php?vt=home&gender=Female");},100);
            }
        }
    }
},2000);
});
```

**Here is my PhP code**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['records'])) {
    $gender = $_POST['gender']; 
    $query  = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE gender = '".$gender."' AND status = 'approved' AND votes > 0 ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 1");
    $data   = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    echo $data[4];
}
?>
```

Comment: You have `if(isset($_GET['records']))` in the beginning of your php code but i dont see it to be set

Comment: This is where you refresh the div right???`$("#ratewomen").load("includes/votings.php?vt=home&gender=Female"`.But in your $_GET parameters  `records` is not set...Am i missing something?

Comment: yes correct and updated

Comment: Where do you POST your data? I see `var vars = "records=records&gender=Female";` but i dont see you use it somewhere

Comment: updated and still not working for me though i am getting time format to be in 1462777955 this format inserted using time() function of php i believe the javascript if condition is not matching though am i correct

Comment: I think you are missing something like `req.send(vars);` to POST your data.Also show your whole php code so I will be able to help you.

Comment: Is my javascript correct or am i missing something

Comment: lol i missed that now got this error in my console log Uncaught ReferenceError: myDate is not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111398/discussion-between-george-pant-and-mark-alan).

Comment: figured out the mistake and solved out but the problem is that my criteria does not match or not matching up what should i do this is the response i got Current Time1462787839515 got from javascript  Time from database 1462787685 like if user clicks on vote so how would be check though

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery for refresh div.

```
 $('.your_button').on('click', function(){
         $('#divLogin').load('your_page_url_here');
    });
```

Comment: it is by clicking and that i don't want to be done I want it to be done automatically what so if 1 user has opened the page in front of him a reviewing the results second user comes and update the result user 1 will not see the updated result until unless he refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...
`

```
    <?php 
       if(isset($_GET['records'])) {
       $gender = $_GET['gender']; 
       $query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE gender = '$gender' 
       AND   status = 'approved' AND votes > 0 ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 1");
       $data   = mysql_fetch_array($query);
       echo $data[4];
      }
      ?>
`
```

Comment: I beleive you only chnaged the query result is getting back perfectly but javascript  is not updating the reconds